# Intellij IDEA gateway can't connect to localhost SSH

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-development

I am running linux and have some projects in another local user account, so want to open it via SSH in Intellij IDEA (Ultimate 2022.2) Remote Development. In terminal and VS code I have no problem to SSH into this user account by a key pair, and I can open projects in VS code. But in IDEA, it keeps saying "Cannot connect to remote host". In configuration UI, I put "127.0.0.1" in host, port 22, username, empty Local port, and select "Key pair" as Authentication type, and then select Private key file (/home/my_username/.ssh/id_rsa). I tried to clear everything in ~/.ssh folder, with only private key in there, but no avail. Is this a known problem, or I missed something?

Comment: hello, if possible can you please create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CWM and attach the logs files to it. Thank you

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Done. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-6968/Intellij-IDEA-gateway-cant-connect-to-another-local-user-account-by-SSH-for-development